How to paint imported obj or fbx model?
I have helicopter obj or fbx file which is I will use in Unity 3D. now what I want to do is import those obj or fbx helicopter model to blender and paint the surface to white or black color.
here are URLs of model in grabcad: https://grabcad.com/library/sikorsky-uh-60-black-hawk-1,
https://grabcad.com/library/sikorsky-uh-60-blackhawk-1
and this youtube video is what I watched to get an idea how to paint model: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjS_zNQNVlw.
I imported model to blender but I can't texture paint on my model because there is no texture selection window.
I need to paint the surface so that is loos like color of helicopter similar to the one seen from IR camera.
I would be really grateful if you provide me help.

Grant says in his tutorial that it is not for complete beginners... sorry no offense, but you sound like an absolute beginner if you have no idea how to get an image texture to paint on. I would highly recommend watching beginner tutorials on texture painting or even materials and shaders in general (if your goal was just to get a fully white or black surface, there will no painting be necessary anyway). This site is to help with specific issues where you got stuck, not to give full walkthroughs on texturing techniques.

And as it stands, it is unclear what materials your object has, what textures and why you cannot locate them or why you cannot paint on them... I actually do not think the model comes without any of these, but since I have to create an account there with full name, email, phone number, company name, position etc. which is data I'm not willing to give for my private voluntary help here, I cannot download the model to check for myself.
